# Google Action Console blocking to starting new release on deploy > Release

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to "starting new release" on Google Action Console > deploy > Release, but Google Action Console is blocking and showing an alert box saying "Please fill out required app information fields before submitting."

[image: as in this screenshot]

where to find the required app information fields?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that **is** pretty vague.

In this case, make sure that all the required fields for all the tabs on the left have been filled out. This includes the Directory Information, company Details, and Brand Verification if necessary.